# What is the difference between 'Here comes the bus' and 'the bus is coming'?

Tags: grammar, differences, tenses, syntactic-analysis

I am confused about when to use the two sentences below( in which situations). They look similar to me.

a. Here comes the bus.

b. The bus is coming.

source:
https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130225020139AAkbjkn

Comment: They mean essentially the same thing, in "average" circumstances, except that option one implies a hair more immediacy -- ie, the bus is in sight, vs simply knowing that it's somewhere en route.

Answer (score 1):

What's confusing you is that you're ignoring that *movement-towards-this-location* is already implicit in the word *come.* Any **extra** word about location is going to be about clarifying or emphasizing something else.

> **The bus is coming.**

already means "The bus is in the process of moving here". It is moving in this direction and will be here eventually, probably soonish but maybe not depending on the rest of the context.

> **Here comes the bus.**

has foregrounded the bus's location and means "Hey! Look over there. You can see the bus coming this way right now." Similarly, "There goes the bus" means you just missed it. You can still see it over there, driving away.

You didn't ask about it, but

> **The bus is coming here.**

is different as well. The bus is coming here as opposed to some other place that was under discussion.